# Take all files in dir and for each file do the same perl procedure

Tags: linux, shell, script

I have dir, where are multiple files. 
`a1`, `bb2`,  `ccc3`

At the moment I  manually do:

```
perl myperscitpt.pl a1 a1.txt
perl myperscitpt.pl bb2 bb2.txt
perl myperscitpt.pl ccc3 ccc3.txt
```

How could I do that by a linux shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *; do perl myperlscript $i ${i%.*}.txt; done
```

It uses regex, of course.

Comment: There is a mistake in the reply. The script will be additionally called with parameters `ls ls.txt`. Also the suffix removal does not use regex it uses the same pattern as in pathname expansion. The suffix removal is not probably needed. The OP did not request it and it makes the code dependant on Bash. Fixed version: `for i in * ; do perl myperlscript $i $i.txt ; done`

Answer (score 2):

you will need to look into for loops.
This guide is superb: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#EX22

so, for every file you could write a loop like this:

```
for fn in *;
do
    # do something with the file names and files
    # make the output filename
    ofn=${fn}.txt
    # run the perl thingy
    perl myperscitpt.pl $fn $ofn
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /home/user/my/folder -type f -exec perl myperscitpt.pl "{}" "{}.txt" \;
```

This command will find all files under a directory (and subdirectory) and execute your perl script.

```
find /home/user/my/folder -type f -iname "a*" -or -iname "b*" -or -iname "c*" -exec perl myperscitpt.pl "{}" "{}.txt" \;
```

You can substitute `/home/user/my/folder` with a dot `.` if you want to search the current folder.

`{}` is the path to the filename (and the filename).

`\;` is required when you use -exec at the end of the command

`-type f` means find files (not directories)

`-iname "a*" -or -iname "b*" -or -iname "c*"` means to search for files that start with a or b or c. `-iname` is *case-insensitive*, `-name` is case-sensitive.

This command *will search in subdirectories* too. If you don't want to search in subdirs, you set the `-maxdepth` (use it as a first argument in your find command):

```
find /home/user/my/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "a*" -or -iname "b*" -or -iname "c*" -exec perl myperscitpt.pl "{}" "{}.txt" \;
```

find is a powerful command with a lot of options, see the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Finding-Files